# How to select data from database Mysql and add it on DataGridView?

Tags: c#, mysql, database, select

The purpose of this is in case you have loaded of data and you want to search using `textbox` the person's name, number and etc and type his name, it will added by directly to an empty data gridview by clicking button.

```
 string box = txtSearch.Text;
            string table = "reservations";
            string query = "SELECT FROM reservations WHERE Client like '%" + box;
            connection.Open();
            MySqlDataAdapter da_res = null;
            DataSet ds_res = null;
            ds_res = new DataSet();
            da_res = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, connection);
            da_res.Fill(ds_res, table);

            dgvUser.DataSource = ds_res.Tables[table];
```

Here's the code actually I have 6 colums I only tried one so far. The erorr occurs on   `da_res.Fill(ds_res, table);`

this is the erorr details :

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM reservations WHERE Client like '%name client' at line 1"

```
MySqlConnection connection = null;
            string hostname = "localhost";
            string database = "aparece_hoteldb";
            string username = "root";
            string password = "";
            connection = new MySqlConnection("host=" + hostname +
                                            ";database=" + database +
                                            ";username=" + username +
                                            ";password=" + password + ";");
```

Comment: if I'm done doing this then i'm totally done with my program any help will be a GREAT GREAT relief to me.

Comment: have you tried anything yet  by yourself ?

Comment: I already have the code but I'm clueless

Comment: I mean it didn't work.

Comment: please post the code that you have tried and didn't work for you, people will help you but they will not write your code for you, this is a pretty common subject for any programmer.

Comment: So what went wrong here ? an error message ? if so please post it as well ...

Comment: what is the error message ?!

Comment: I posted it please see

Comment: will you just please give me an example a website like what i want to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chage this :

```
string query = "SELECT FROM reservations WHERE Client like '%" + box;
```

to This:

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM reservations WHERE Client like '%" + box +"%'";
```

You are not selecting any columns.

and as you asked here is a working example for you (you really need to learn to use google)...

```
private void MainClass_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    string connectionString = @"Driver={MySQL};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=NorthwindMySQL;";

    OdbcConnection conn= new OdbcConnection(connectionString);
    conn.Open();

    OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter ("SELECT CustomerID, ContactName, ContactTitle FROM Customers", conn);            

    DataSet ds = new DataSet("Cust");     
    da.Fill(ds, "Customers");

    dataGrid1.DataSource = ds.DefaultViewManager;
    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: by the way in your code where is the connection string ? is it a member of the class ?

Comment: just notieced that you where also missing a closing (') in your SQL query, see my edit.

Comment: Anyway Thank you for the example!

Comment: WOW THANk YOU for your help I figure out the problem :D. I DID IT!